# Dynamic INSERT INTO ... EXEC available?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My task is to write a stored procedure (`sp2`) that does work based on an another stored procedure's (`sp1`) returned result. Logic consistency is absolutely strict, so my solution is using `INSERT INTO ... EXEC` in `sp2` to make an expedient approach.

The code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp2
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #t(column1 int, column2 int)

    INSERT INTO #t
        EXEC dbo.sp1

    --- then do many things
END

---- Existing stored procedure "sp1"
--ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp1
--AS
--BEGIN
   -- do many things
   --SELECT <something> as column1, <something2> as column2
   --FROM ...
--END
```

The problems lays when the structure of output `sp1` is changed, even just add a column; when this happens, `sp2` will be certainly down, and its too difficult for `sp1` modifier to be aware of this if related testings are not available.

If we know `sp1` will only add outputs rather than decrease or modify existing, is there any way to keep `sp2` online even when `sp1` is modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql)

Here's a [tutorial](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-how-to-insert-data-from-stored-procedure-to-table-2-different-methods/) that shows its use in the manner you're looking for

Comment: @sepupic This is mentioned in the tutorial

Comment: thanks for the idea, pity this feature is not allowed in this server. But I've found alternative ways out of SQL scope to solve my problem.